# How to make 3 word inputs and search on these in 3 specific columns in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, search

I'm trying to make a program that search three words out of three columns. 
This is my search input, but I think it is not the right way to make it.

```
 <form action="resultaat.php" method="post"> 
    <b>Typ Postcode:</b> <input type="text" name="term" />
    <b>Typ Huisnummer:</b> <input type="text" name="term2" />
    <b>Typ Toevoeging:</b>  <input type="text" name="term3" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Zoek" />
 </form>
```

And this is my sql code:

```
mysql_connect ("localhost", "root","")  or die (mysql_error());
        mysql_select_db ("inboedelmeter");

        $term = $_POST['term'];
        $term2= $_POST['term2'];
        $term3 = $_POST['term3'];

        $sql = mysql_query("select * from inboedelwaarde_adres where Postcode like '$term' and Huisnummer like '$term2' and Toevoeging like '$term3'");
```

It seems for me like the right way, but it does not work.. 
Can anybody help me with this?
Thanks!

Comment: Can you elaborate on "did not work"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do an exact search,

```
 $sql = mysql_query("select * from inboedelwaarde_adres where Postcode 
 = '$term' and Huisnummer ='$term2' and Toevoeging = '$term3'");
```

Comment: I asked the question wrong. I want to search three words in three specific columns. And the terms need to be exact.